# in orchard why does manually adding entries to the database not work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, orchardcms

I am using the Advanced Menu for Orchard, I have alot of duplicated content to add to multiple menus so was trying to do this directly into the database.

The problem I had was when I add items to the database the items don't show up and the CMS breaks and doesn't allow items to be added (this causes a duplicate primary key error).

Can anyone tell me why this is, and what I would need to do if I wanted to add entries manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing how you've tried to add them, it's hard to say. Maybe you've created part records without content item records, making them orphans? But again, I'm just guessing, as I have no idea what you tried to do.

Comment: I was adding extra entries to Szmyd_Orchard_Modules_Menu_AdvancedMenuItemPartRecord
by incrementing the id and position and inserting directly in to this table, basically I have the same repeated subsections for each menu item and was trying to enter these without having to use the CMS

Comment: Yes, don't do that. You created orphan content parts. You would need to create the corresponding content items for this to have a remote chance of working.

Answer (score 1):

For manual entries you might be better off using the command line utility.  see http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Using-the-command-line-interface.ashx

Or the import/export functionality (which I think just runs the command line stuff)

If yo want to know more follow piotr's blog.  It's full of great stuff!
http://www.szmyd.com.pl/